# Where is Microsoft.Exchange.RecipientTasks located

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, exchange-server

I am trying to automate a process that gets and sets mailbox permissions using remote powershell via an automated exchange pipeline. The AccessRights property of the Get-MailboxPermission command output is of type Microsoft.Exchange.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights []. I cannot find this namespace anywhere on nuget and it does not appear to be part of the EWS api, as far as I can tell. Does anyone know where this namespace can be found so I can reference it in my project, or if there is a way to cast the output as a standard object type?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Remote Powershell you have deserialized types https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/ so the server side types aren't what you should be using at that point. All you need to do is something like

```
        Command getmbPerms = new Command("Get-MailboxPermission");
        getmbPerms.Parameters.Add("Identity", Mailbox);
        Pipeline plPileLine = Runspace.CreatePipeline();
        plPileLine.Commands.Add(getmbPerms);
        Collection<PSObject> RsResultsresults = plPileLine.Invoke();
        foreach (PSObject obj in RsResultsresults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["User"].Value.ToString());
            PSObject AccessRights = (PSObject)obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value;
            System.Collections.ArrayList AccessRightsCol = (System.Collections.ArrayList)AccessRights.BaseObject;
            foreach (String Permission in AccessRightsCol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Permission);
            }

        }
        plPileLine.Stop();
```

and then just parse the Enums out of the String. When you Set rights for a user the AccessRights parameter is just a string that matches the server side enums.

```
        Command AddPermissions = new Command("Add-MailboxPermission");
        AddPermissions.Parameters.Add("Identity", Mailbox);
        AddPermissions.Parameters.Add("User", UserName);
        AddPermissions.Parameters.Add("AccessRights", "FullAccess");
        AddPermissions.Parameters.Add("AutoMapping", false);
```

Comment: Hi Glen Thank you for the reply. I did try this earlier, but tried again and can confirm that that trying to cast Microsoft.Exchange.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights []. as a PSObject fails with a 'cannot cast as type' error. I am starting to think that maybe this isn't possible :(

Comment: Doesn't sound correct to me what I posted is working code it sounds like you have issues somewhere else (eg your not using remote powershell maybe you have loaded the snapin ??). You should be able to see the types if you run it in a debugger.